# Entity Framework Core 7.0.15 throws Invalid Cast Expection on AutoInclude

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, blazor

I have the following `DbContext` using a TPC mapping strategy to add basic fields to all entities and in the background a Postgresql database server and .NET 6.0.

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

// devices tracking
public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
public DbSet<DeviceLending> DevicesLendings { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Default values from db functions
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<DbBase>()
        .UseTpcMappingStrategy()
        .Property(e => e.Created)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("now()");

    // Auto Includes
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Device>()
        .Navigation(e => e.Lendings)
        .AutoInclude();

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<DeviceLending>()
        .Navigation(e => e.Device)
        .AutoInclude();
}
```

The `DbBase` class looks like this:

```
public abstract class DbBase
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public Instant Created { get; set; }
    public Instant Updated { get; set; }
    
    [Timestamp]
    public uint Version { get; set; }
}
```

And the actual data classes like this:

```
public class Device : DbBase
{
    public ICollection<DeviceLending> Lendings { get; } = new List<DeviceLending>();
    public string Comment { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class DeviceLending : DbBase
{
    public string Comment { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Now when I try to load the devices including the `Lendings` property I get an exception

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'devices.Entities.Device' to type 'devices.Entities.DeviceLending'

Why is EF Core trying to load the `Device` type as `Lendings` which are of the type `DeviceLending`? Is this related to the TPC mapping strategy?

I tried commenting out the `AutoInclude`, then it worked but I need the lendings to be included. Also is tried adding a setter to the lending property but this didn't change anything.

I have found other issues like this only but they dated back 5 years and were a bug on EF Core which is fixed in my version.

The full exception:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
>
> Unhandled exception in circuit '5xqWOiz4ASoSDGW8EUUVSgQvQ-XQTuwqp0axa7fVeFk'.
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'devices.Entities.Device' to type 'devices.Entities.DeviceLending'.
>
> at lambda_method90(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.g__ProcessCurrentElementRow|24_0[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity](<>c__DisplayClass24_0`2& )   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeCollection[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity](Int32 collectionId, QueryContext queryContext, DbDataReader dbDataReader, SingleQueryResultCoordinator resultCoordinator, Func`3 parentIdentifier, Func`3 outerIdentifier, Func`3 selfIdentifier, IReadOnlyList`1 parentIdentifierValueComparers, IReadOnlyList`1 outerIdentifierValueComparers, IReadOnlyList`1 selfIdentifierValueComparers, Func`5 innerShaper, INavigationBase inverseNavigation, Action`2 fixup, Boolean trackingQuery) at lambda_method92(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator ) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at devices.Services.DbService.GetDevicesAsync(CancellationToken ct) in [redacted]/Services/DbService.cs:line 68
> at devices.Shared.DeviceGrid.LoadDevices() in [redacted]/Shared/DeviceGrid.razor:line 40
> at devices.Shared.DeviceGrid.OnInitializedAsync() in [redacted]/Shared/DeviceGrid.razor:line 45
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

Comment: Are you sure that EF picks up that Device and Lendings are the counterparts of the same FK?

Comment: Yes EFCore auto discovers the relationship. I verified this by looking at the created tables in  the database.

Comment: Why do you need/want table inheritance at all for these classes? You can use a base class for common fields without a DbBase "entity" defined with TPC etc. Just have the subclass entities themselves mapped to their desired tables. TPC/TPH etc. are meant for relationships that are inherited and interchangable. Is there any need for any relationship to be associated with either Device and/or DeviceLending interchangeably?

Comment: ahh okay. I didn't know that I can use inheritance without using a speical mapping strategy.